# How to remove commits with rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have the following commit tree :

```
D         (HEAD, origin/develop, develop)
| \
|  C
B  |
| /
A         (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
```

I'd like to remove commits B and C from history and keep the changes made into them. So D source files will be the same after the operations. Only the git history will be changed.

I tried :
`git rebase -i A` from D with the options :

```
pick B 
pick C
```

then I have a merge error :

```
warning: Cannot merge binary files: MyFile.bin (HEAD vs. C... )

Automatic cherry-pick failed.  After resolving the conflicts,
mark the corrected paths with 'git add <paths>', and
run 'git rebase --continue'
Could not apply C...
```

So I correct my conflicts, make a `git rebase --continue` and I get :

```
E           (HEAD, develop)
| D         (origin/develop)
| |\
|/ /
|  C
B  |
| /
A         (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
```

Whereas I'd like to have :

```
E  (or D, the sources files are the same in D & E)
|
A
```

I don't understand why B is still in the way from A to E. What should I do now ? I'm a little confused

Comment: Why did you choose `pick B` and `pick C` when you wanted to *remove* them?

Comment: Well, I want to keep the changes made in B and C. May I have misunderstood what pick means ?

Comment: You can rebase again. this time `pick B` and `squash E` and this should merge both versions into one commit. (Or from the original rebase: `pick B`, `squash C`).

Comment: If `E` is in the state you want, you can now use `git rebase -i A E` and use `pick B`, `squash E` (or `fixup E`).

Comment: @mkrieger1 This is creating a new commit F directly from A. Source files in F are the same as E and D.  HEAD points to F. develop points to E. origin/develop points to D. How can I clean that now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments, I have done this :

```
git rebase -i A

pick B
squash C
```

Then I've corrected the conflicts and ran the `git rebase --continue`

After that the tree looked like this :

```
E         (HEAD, develop)
| D       (origin/develop)
| |\
| | C
| |/
|/|
| B
|/
A         (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
```

To get the origin/develop to point on E, I've made a `git push --force`. After that, I had exactly what I wanted :

```
E         (HEAD, origin/develop, develop)
A         (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
```